# Select data based on multiple criteria with Pandas/python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes, the first one has a column for direction like the following:

```
In [9]:wtg_data[1][['U_all', 'Dir_all']].head()
Out[9]: 
                        U_all   Dir_all
timestamp                             
2015-05-09 00:00:00  6.425383  192.7583
2015-05-09 00:10:00  6.736392  196.0836
2015-05-09 00:20:00  7.613443  203.2848
2015-05-09 00:30:00  7.539424  203.4758
2015-05-09 00:40:00  7.365549  205.2733
```

The second one has a set of sections that I need to exclude defined by a start and end angle like the following:

```
In [16]:wake_exclusion_zone[1][['end_angle', 'start_angle']]
Out[16]: 
     end_angle  start_angle
0          NaN          NaN
1    92.766080    37.683639
2     4.587928   296.557159
3    58.302667     6.732354
4   354.386611   305.505815
5    35.865741   324.134259
6   353.667108   313.202790
7    24.513812   335.486188
8   356.721479   321.058398
9    18.416798   341.583202
10  358.340554   325.613169
11   14.495289   342.304661
```

I would like to select (and save in a different df) the data from the first dataframe that the direction (Dir_all column) is between any of the sectors defined by the pairs in the second df.

At the moment I have tried the following that works for the first section

```
export = wtg_data[1][(wtg_data[1]['Dir_all'] > wake_exclusion_zone[1]['start_angle'][1]) & (wtg_data[1]['Dir_all'] < wake_exclusion_zone[1]['end_angle'][1])]
```

but then when I try to loop through the second df and append the data `export` df stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) all rows of first dataframe `df1` with all rows of second dataframe `df2` and then filter output:

Output was no data, so I change first and second rows of `df1`.

```
print df1
                          U_all   Dir_all
timestamp                                
2015-05-09 00:00:00  200.000000   92.7583
2015-05-09 00:00:00  200.000000   92.7583
2015-05-09 00:10:00    6.736392  196.0836
2015-05-09 00:20:00    7.613443  203.2848
2015-05-09 00:30:00    7.539424  203.4758
2015-05-09 00:40:00    7.365549  205.2733

print df2
     end_angle  start_angle
0          NaN          NaN
1    92.766080    37.683639
2     4.587928   296.557159
3    58.302667     6.732354
4   354.386611   305.505815
5    35.865741   324.134259
6   353.667108   313.202790
7    24.513812   335.486188
8   356.721479   321.058398
9    18.416798   341.583202
10  358.340554   325.613169
11   14.495289   342.304661
```

```
#helper column for join
df1['i'] = 1
df2['i'] = 1

df1 = df1.reset_index()

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['i'])
#condition
df = df[(df.Dir_all > df.start_angle) & (df.Dir_all <= df.end_angle)]
#remove helper
df = df.drop(['i'], axis=1)
print df
    timestamp  U_all  Dir_all  end_angle  start_angle
1  2015-05-09    200  92.7583   92.76608    37.683639
13 2015-05-09    200  92.7583   92.76608    37.683639

#set index from column timestamp
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
#drop duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates(['U_all','Dir_all','end_angle', 'start_angle'])
print df
            U_all  Dir_all  end_angle  start_angle
timestamp                                         
2015-05-09    200  92.7583   92.76608    37.683639
```

Comment: Thanks.This does work but creates two problems. First I loose the index which in this case is the date that I wanted and I can't find a way to keep it singe after merging index will not have unique values. And second I now have duplicate values if a record meets multiple criteria.

Comment: This has solved my problem. One more thing for some reason 'timestamp' as a column name creates ambiguity. I don't know why but I had to change it was getting random errors.